# set ionic toggle from localstorage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, toggle

html:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="favorite.checked" ng-change="favoriteChange()"> favorite </ion-toggle>
```

js:

```
$scope.favorite = {};

$scope.favorite.checked = $window.localStorage.getItem("favorites");

if($scope.favorite.checked === null) {
    $scope.favorite.checked = true;
}

    $scope.favoriteChange = function() {
    $window.localStorage.setItem("favorites", $scope.favorite.checked);
};
```

I have the toggle above in my app, when I close the app and restart it, I can see that the value is stored correct in localstorage but the toggle displays default value.
Can anyone see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

my fault! I'm dealing with 2 controllers, in 2nd controller I also need to load the value from localstorage.